# PL/SQL - Can you access certain record in a cursor by index?

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I am trying to write a test, and given a group of reviews, I want to set **1** of them to 'Status A' and **all of the rest** to 'Status B'. I know for PL/SQL, there is a FOR LOOP syntax for a CURSOR, and I got it so it can process all of the reviews, but is there a way to access a specific record in that cursor?

I think what would solve my problem is a way to access the Cursor by Index, similar to how you can access an array by index in other languages. **Is there a way to do that in PL/SQL?**

I am still quite new to the syntax of PL/SQL and cursors, so I will write out what I am wanting to do in pseudocode.

### Pseudocode

```
CURSOR c_reviewer_ids IS
    SELECT id FROM reviewer_tbl
    WHERE course_id = 123;
v_first_id   reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE;

FOR i in 0..c_reviewer_ids.length
{
   IF i == 0
   {
      v_first_id := c_reviewer_ids(i);

      UPDATE reviewer_tbl
      SET status = 'Status A'
      WHERE id = c_reviewer_ids(i);
   }
   ELSE
   {
      UPDATE reviewer_tbl
      SET status = 'Status B'
      WHERE id = c_reviewer_ids(i);
   }
}
```

I was able to make a CURSOR FOR LOOP, but it handles every record the same, and I want to do something special for just one record. This is what I currently have:

### CURSOR FOR LOOP (doesn't handle special case)

```
  CURSOR c_reviewer_ids IS
    SELECT id FROM reviewer_tbl
    WHERE course_id = 123;
  v_reviewer_id   reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE;

  FOR l_reviewer_id IN c_reviewer_ids 
  LOOP
      --Set the status for all reviewers.
      UPDATE reviewer_tbl
      SET status = 'Status B'
      WHERE reviewer_id = l_reviewer_id.id;

      --Save one of the ids; for this particular test, it doesn't matter if it is first or not
      v_reviewer_id := l_reviewer_id.id;
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Why do you need a curser at all?  Would a `case` construct not do the trick?

Comment: @dan-bracuk, I do not know the Reviewer IDs before the test, so I would not be able to use them as conditions to switch on in the `case` statement. I only care to switch based on whether one record in the `select` result has been handled differently. A boolean flag would be enough for my specific case... Perhaps the combination of a `boolean` and the `case` would work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this from the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm#CIHICHBI), I found a way to use an `INDEX-BY` table that most closely matches what I wanted in my pseudocode. It creates the cursor, and then puts it to a temporary table, which can then be indexed.

After writing the code out, I realised that the cursor may not be that necessary, since it is immediately closed. In that case, the cursor can be omitted and only the `INDEX BY` table is used (similar to what Carlo wrote in his answer).

### Using index-by table ALONG WITH cursor

```
DEFINE
    CURSOR c_reviewer_ids IS
        SELECT id FROM reviewer_tbl
        WHERE course_id = 123;

    --table type
    TYPE reviewer_id_tbl_type IS TABLE OF c_reviewer_ids%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    --actual table
    t_reviewer_ids reviewer_id_tbl_type;

    v_first_id   reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    --Fetch the cursor into the indexed table
    OPEN c_reviewer_ids;
    FETCH c_reviewer_ids BULK COLLECT INTO t_reviewer_ids;
    CLOSE c_reviewer_ids;  --cursor won't be used anymore

    --For loop
    FOR i IN 1..t_reviewer_ids.COUNT()  LOOP
       IF i = 1 THEN
          v_first_id := t_reviewer_ids(i).id;

          UPDATE reviewer_tbl
          SET status = 'Status A'
          WHERE id = t_reviewer_ids(i).id;
       ELSE
          UPDATE reviewer_tbl
          SET status = 'Status B'
          WHERE id = t_reviewer_ids(i).id;
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

### Using index-by table INSTEAD OF cursor

```
DEFINE
    --table type
    TYPE reviewer_id_tbl_type IS TABLE OF reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    --actual table
    t_reviewer_ids reviewer_id_tbl_type;

    v_first_id   reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    --Fetch the query into the indexed table
    SELECT id
    BULK COLLECT INTO t_reviewer_ids
    FROM reviewer_tbl
    WHERE course_id = 123;

    --For loop; Notice that .id is not needed anymore
    FOR i IN 1..t_reviewer_ids.COUNT()  LOOP
       IF i = 1 THEN
          v_first_id := t_reviewer_ids(i); 

          UPDATE reviewer_tbl
          SET status = 'Status A'
          WHERE id = t_reviewer_ids(i);
       ELSE
          UPDATE reviewer_tbl
          SET status = 'Status B'
          WHERE id = t_reviewer_ids(i);
       END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a BOOLEAN to tell you if you've processed the "first" row from the cursor, in a manner similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_reviewer_ids IS
    SELECT id FROM reviewer_tbl
      WHERE course_id = 123;
  v_reviewer_id   reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE;
  bFirst_row      BOOLEAN := TRUE;
BEGIN
  FOR l_reviewer_id IN c_reviewer_ids 
  LOOP
    IF bFirst_row THEN
      bFirst_row := FALSE;

      UPDATE reviewer_tbl
        SET status = 'Status A'
        WHERE id = l_reviewer_id.ID;
    ELSE
      --Set the status for all other reviewers.
      UPDATE reviewer_tbl
        SET status = 'Status B'
        WHERE reviewer_id = l_reviewer_id.ID;
    END IF;

    --Save one of the ids; for this particular test, it doesn't matter if it is first or not
    v_reviewer_id := l_reviewer_id.id;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Best of luck.

### EDIT

If you want to access the fifth row you could do something like:

```
DECLARE
  v_reviewer_id   reviewer_tbl.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR l_reviewer_id IN (SELECT id, RN
                          FROM (SELECT ID, ROWNUM AS RN
                                  FROM reviewer_tbl
                                  WHERE course_id = 123)
                          WHERE RN = 5)
  LOOP
      UPDATE reviewer_tbl
        SET status = 'Status A'
        WHERE id = l_reviewer_id.ID;

    --Save one of the ids; for this particular test, it doesn't matter if it is first or not
    v_reviewer_id := l_reviewer_id.id;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you - this was able to handle my specific problem. :)
I am still curious though if there is a more general solution... for instance, what if I needed to access the 5th row? Is there a way to access the record of index 5?

Comment: There is no 5th row until five rows have been fetched. The complete result set doesn't exist in some internal store waiting for you to access it. You could add a computed row number to the cursor using the `row_number()` analytic function, if that helps.

Comment: See my edit to the answer. Also note that in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause the concept of "fifth row" is arbitrary. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can load all the query results into an actual memory array using a "BULK COLLECT INTO" clause and then use regular index-based access to that array.

This is not memory efficient *(so be aware that you shouldn't do this if you are processing tons of records)*, but it works:

See this example where I load in a memory array the first 100 records of the "DICT" system view:

```
 declare
    type MEMTABLE_TYPE is 
        TABLE OF DICT%ROWTYPE index by binary_integer;

    myarray MEMTABLE_TYPE;
 begin
   select * 
   BULK COLLECT INTO myarray -- this loads the whole query result into the array
   from DICT
   where rownum < 100;

   -- scan all the array: 
   for c in 1..myarray.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line(myarray(c).table_name ||' -> ' || myarray(c).comments);
   end loop;             

   -- access directly the fifth element  
   dbms_output.put_line(myarray(5).table_name ||' -> ' || myarray(5).comments);
 end;
```

Anyway you shouldn't abuse this: unless you need to access the data multiple times (so keeping it in memory instead of re-executing the query could speed up things) you should try to use a regular cursor.